# Error in creating a day column from date in Python - Pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I am trying to create a day column from date. When I do this it works perfectly:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse(dta.date[0]).strftime("%A")
```

`Output: 'Tuesday'`

But when I am trying to create new column like this:

```
dta['week_day'] = parser.parse(dta['date']).strftime("%A")
```

It gives me an error:

`TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not Series`

```
dta.info()
```

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 107927 entries, 0 to 107926
Data columns (total 16 columns):
date          107927 non-null object
dep_hour      107927 non-null int64
dep_minute    107927 non-null int64
dep_time      107927 non-null int64
dep_delay     107927 non-null int64
arr_hour      107927 non-null int64
arr_minute    107927 non-null int64
arr_time      107927 non-null int64
arr_delay     107927 non-null int64
carrier       107927 non-null object
tailnum       107927 non-null object
flight        107927 non-null int64
origin        107927 non-null object
dest          107927 non-null object
air_time      107927 non-null int64
distance      107927 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(11), object(5)`

Date looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you put your `dta` object here?

Comment: Done @FrankAK!!

Comment: Can you print out `dta['date']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `.apply` function on the Series at the column name `date`.

```
from dateutil import parser
import pandas as pd

dta = pd.DataFrame([{"date":"10/20/2017"},{"date":"1/5/2017"},{"date":"5/30/2017"}])
dta['date'] = dta['date'].apply(lambda date:parser.parse(date).strftime("%A"))
print(dta)
```

Outputs:

```
       date
0    Friday
1  Thursday
2   Tuesday
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. But I still didn't get what was wrong with my code.

Comment: Python isn't designed with dataframes and series in mind.  So, you can't just take any function and assume it will loop through every item in your Series.  You, instead, have to create your own function that takes the input data and then changes it using the function you wish to use.  Processing one item through your desired function at a time.